# Update SQL statement only if two values match in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been searching for this scenario that has come across my desk, I have been searching reference sites but haven't had luck creating the correct SQL statement to complete this task.

Here is the PSEUDO code for the scenario.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET TABLE1.ID = TABLE1.From_ID,
    TABLE1.VALUE = 'ALL'
WHERE TABLE1.From_ID = TABLE2.ID
  AND TABLE2.NAME = 'TEST'
```

Basically I need to update two columns in TABLE1 only if the id from TABLE1 matches the ID's in the TABLE2 and the description column in TABLE2 equals to a string value the caveat is that TABL1 columns can't be change only if there is a correlation between the ID's from TABLE1 and TABLE2 and in TABLE2 that ID correlates to description column for a specific string value. Below is table structure and end result I'm trying to get too.

`TABLE1`:

```
FIELD_ID    CONDITIONAL_VALUE   FROM_FIELDID
--------------------------------------------   
   1        TEST                   3
   7        TEST                   4
   5        ANY                    7
```

`TABLE2`:

```
FIELD_ID   Description
----------------------------------------------
   3       BLUE
   4       BLUE
   7       RED
```

Comment: Could you please get your narrative, your code and the table structure in sync?

Comment: Thanks Dean, I will start to format correctly, first time using site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Transact-SQL (SQL Server's dialect of SQL), you need a `FROM` clause in your SQL if you specify more than the table you're trying to update.

`update 
    TABLE1.ID 
set 
    TABLE1.ID = TABLE1.From_ID , 
    TABLE1.VALUE = 'ALL'
from
    TABLE1,
    TABLE2
where 
    TABLE1.From_ID  = TABLE2.ID 
    AND TABLE2.NAME = ''TEST`

Comment: ugh... the old obsolete `table1,table2` join syntax rears it's ugly head.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was trying to use his code as much as possible, to minimize the changes he had to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join data from `TABLE1` to `TABLE2`

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.ID = t1.From_ID
       ,t1.VALUE = 'ALL'
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON t1.From_ID = t2.ID
           AND t2.NAME = 'TEST't1
```

Comment: Thanks for Sharing, I'm looking into this example.